# Como generar el instalador .IPA para IOS IPhone en un proyecto Ionic2?

Tags: ionic, cordova, iphone

estoy trabajando con Ionic2 sobre un "SO Mac X Capitan"

luego de ejecutar el comando: `ionic build ios` y/o `ionic emulate ios`
me sale

```
/Users/AppPrueba/platforms/ios/build/emulator/AppPrueba.app
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

yo quiero obtener el instalador `.IPA` para instalarlo en un IPhone, o para subirlo en [DeployGate](https://deploygate.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
ionic build --release ios
pushd platforms/ios/

xcodebuild -scheme "$1" -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath "build/$1.xcarchive"

xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "build/$1.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/$1.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "$2"
```

Basado en este [gist](https://gist.github.com/six519/89149db44391479ff45f)

Answer (score 0):

Con este comando te debería valer

```
ionic build ios --device --release
```

Pero necesitas un fichero build.json  en la raiz de tu proyecto como este

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "provisioningProfile": "UUID-del-provisioning-profile-de-desarrollo"
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "provisioningProfile": "UUID-del-provisioning-profile-de-distribucion"
    }
  }
}
```

Para obtener el UUID yo abro el .mobileprovision en un editor de texto y busco por 'UUID', no se si hay otra forma de encontrarlo

Asegúrate de usar Xcode 7, porque con Xcode 8 ahora mismo hay problemas (Si tienes ambos instalados, con el comando `xcode-select -p` ves si apunta al 7 o al 8 y con `xcode-select -s /ruta/a/Xcode7/Xcode7.app` lo cambias, y si ya no tienes el 7 bajátelo de la web de desarrolladores de Apple)